# Can't get an ImageView in custom AlertDialog within an custom AlertDialog, updated

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

sry for my english..
In my app from Home_Activity, i click on an Button and a custom AlertDialog shows up. Within this AlertDialog(DialogAdd), i click on an ImageView say iv1 (or ImageButton - both didn't work) and another custom AlertDialog opens(Choose) - so far so good. Now i have my 2nd AlertDialog opened and see, say 4 little pictures. When i click on one of these pictures, the second AlertDialog should close and the ImageView (iv1) should change to that choosen icon from AlertDialog 2. I got everything running but not to change this ImageView/ImageButton...
I seperated this behaviour into a little app..

Home_Activity

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class Home_Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_showDialog);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            DialogAdd addEntrieActivity = new DialogAdd(Home_Activity.this);
            addEntrieActivity.createDialogAdd(Home_Activity.this);
        }
    });
}
```

}

DialogAdd

```
import android.content.Context;
        import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
        import android.view.LayoutInflater;
        import android.view.View;
        import android.widget.ImageView;

        public class DialogAdd implements View.OnClickListener, Choose.Choose_Interface {
            private LayoutInflater inflater;
            private View view;
            private Context context;
            private AlertDialog dialog;
            private String selectetSmile = null;
            private ImageView ib_dialog_smile;

            public DialogAdd(final Context context) {

                this.context = context;
                inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_line, null);

                ib_dialog_smile = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.ib_dialog_smile);
                ib_dialog_smile.setOnClickListener(this);
            }

            public void createDialogAdd(Context context) {
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
                inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                builder.setView(view);
                dialog = builder.create();
                dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(android.R.color.transparent);
                dialog.show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(v.getId() == R.id.ib_dialog_smile){
                    Choose choose = new Choose(context);
                    choose.createDialogChoose();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void selectedSmile(String smile) {
                selectetSmile = smile;
                if(selectetSmile.equals("oh")){
                    ib_dialog_smile.setImageResource(R.drawable.oh);
                }else if(selectetSmile.equals("oh_nooo")){
                    ib_dialog_smile.setImageResource(R.drawable.oh_nooo);
                }else if(selectetSmile.equals("oh_what")){
                    ib_dialog_smile.setImageResource(R.drawable.oh_what);
                }else if(selectetSmile.equals("oh_yes")){
                    ib_dialog_smile.setImageResource(R.drawable.oh_yes);
                }
            }
        }
```

Choose

```
public class Choose {

            public interface Choose_Interface {
                void selectedSmile(String flag);
            }

            public Choose_Interface mCallback;
            private View view;
            private Context context;
            private LayoutInflater inflater;
            private AlertDialog dialog;
            private ImageView oh, oh_nooo, oh_what, oh_yes;

            public Choose(final Context context) {
                this.context = context;
                inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.choose, null);
                mCallback = new DialogAdd(context);
                oh = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.oh);
                oh.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        mCallback.selectedSmile("oh");
                        Toast.makeText(context, "oh klicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });
                oh_nooo = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.oh_nooo);
                oh_nooo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        mCallback.selectedSmile("oh_nooo");
                        Toast.makeText(context, "oh_nooo klicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });

                oh_what = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.oh_what);
                oh_what.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        mCallback.selectedSmile("oh_what");
                        Toast.makeText(context, "oh_what klicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });

                oh_yes = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.oh_yes);
                oh_yes.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        mCallback.selectedSmile("oh_yes");
                        Toast.makeText(context, "oh_yes klicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });

            }

            public void createDialogChoose() {
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
                inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                builder.setView(view);
                dialog = builder.create();
                dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(android.R.color.transparent);
                dialog.show();
            }
        }
```

i've tried it with invalidate ib_dialog_smile, i used an ImageButton and also ImageView, AppCompatImageView, setImageDrawable, setImageResource.. but the image didnt get updated.
Can someone please help me out to change ib_dialog_smile image?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I think your code is a little complicated. You don't need seperate classes to create two custom AlertDialogs. Just create two XML layouts each for every dialog and style them the way you want (in the first XML layout put your "chosen" ImageView and the button and in the second the four images).

Let's call them layout_1 (chosen icon) and layout_2 (four options)

then in your home_activity inflate those in a view var and choose them as alertDialog views like this:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //Creating the first dialog.
    AlertDialog.Builder dialogOneBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    View layout1 = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.id.layout_1, null);
    dialogOneBuilder.setView(layout1)
    AlertDialog dialogOne = dialogOneBuilder.show();

    //Finding the chosen icon and button image from dialog 1
    final ImageView chosenIcon = (ImageView)layout1.findViewById(R.id.chosen_icon);
    Button chooseButton = (Button)layout1.findViewById(R.id.choose_button);

    //On button click
    chooseButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        //Creating the second dialog.
        AlertDialog.Builder dialogTwoBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        View layout2 = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.id.layout_2, null);
        dialogTwoBuilder.setView(layout2)
        AlertDialog dialogTwo = dialogTwoBuilder.show();

       //finding the ImageViews of the four choices
       ImageView img1 = (ImageView)layout2.findViewById(R.id.img1);
       ImageView img2 = (ImageView)layout2.findViewById(R.id.img2);
       ImageView img3 = (ImageView)layout2.findViewById(R.id.img3);
       ImageView img4 = (ImageView)layout2.findViewById(R.id.img4);

       //Add them in a LinkedList helps to shrink your code
       LinkedList<ImageView> choices = new LinkedList<>();
       choices.add(img1);
       choices.add(img2);
       choices.add(img3);
       choices.add(img4);

       //Now set ONE ClickListener for all choices
       for(int i = 0; i < choices.size(); i++){
           choices.get(i).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
               //change your icon to the chosen image
               chosenIcon.setImageDrawable(choices.get(i).getDrawable());

               //And close the second dialog.
               dialogTwo.dismiss();
           });
       }
    });
}
```

Worked perfectly for my voting & commenting dialog. Hope this helped you and the code was readable.